# Shifting bytes and remaining values casted to int (interested in two's complement)

Tags: c, optimization, casting, arduino

Why does the code that you see below give these results?

```
void loop() {
    byte test = 00000101;
    Serial.print("The byte test is: ");
    Serial.println(test);
    int x = (int)test;
    int y = (int)test<<8;
    Serial.print("The int x is: ");
    Serial.println(x);
    Serial.print("The int shifted y is: ");
    Serial.println(y);

    byte tost = 10000001;
    int z = test + tost;
    Serial.print("The int z is: ");
    Serial.println(z);

    delay(1000);
}
```

**Results**:

> The byte test is: 65
>
> The int x is: 65
>
> The int shifted y is: 16640
>
> The int z is: 194

While if I change the test to 00000001 it performs great:

**Changed code:**

```
void loop() {
    byte test = 00000001;
    Serial.print("The byte test is: ");
    Serial.println(test);
    int x = (int)test;
    int y = (int)test<<8;
    Serial.print("The int x is: ");
    Serial.println(x);
    Serial.print("The int shifted y is: ");
    Serial.println(y);

    byte tost = 10000001;
    int z = test + tost;
    Serial.print("The int z is: ");
    Serial.println(z);

    delay(1000);
}
```

**Results:**

```
The byte test is: 1

The int x is: 1

The int shifted y is: 256

The int z is: 130
```

My problem is that I have two bytes that I want to read from data registers from an accelerometer. The value is stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) so I wanted to check since `wire.read` returns a byte that some people say that is signed and some unsigned if I destroy the values, because I have to do some shifting.

So I wanted to check if I have a byte and I try to shift it and store it to an int, what values do I get, and I want to test if somehow I can store signed byte values inside a byte array.

Comment: Numbers beginning with 0 are octal, not binary, so 00000101 really is 1*64+0*8+1=65. Are you aware of that?

Comment: What is `byte`? This isn't C, is it?

Comment: @alk Looks like Arduino code, which is C++ more or less.

Comment: Also, 10000001 isn't going to fit in a byte, which I'm guessing is 8 bits long in your system. Results are as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer shown above is correct as Alexy Frunze said number starting with 0 is octal .

```
000000101 is 65 not 5
65 << 8 =16640
10000001 in decimal is 129
129+65 = 194
```

Comment: :( missed that. OK but can you answer me about a value that is read from and stored as byte and these values are in 2's compliment, i suppose that i have to do the translation and casting is not enough?

Answer (score 3):

Just because you write a number that "looks binary" since it has a lot of 1s and 0s and is 8 digits wide, doesn't make it magically a binary literal. How would you expect:

```
byte x = 100;
```

and

```
byte x = 100;
```

to know the value is supposed to be 100<sub>10</sub> (one hunded or 100<sub>2</sub> (four)?

In fact, C (and C++) don't even have binary literals built-in: a numeric literal starting with `0` is interpreted as *octal*, base 8.